# Why isn't my background for the button changing color?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to change the color of both the body and a button when the button itself is clicked.

Right now, the body of the page changes color randomly. However this is not working for the button itself.

Any ideas?

This is my CSS for the button:

```
#loadQuote {
  position: fixed;
  width: 12em;
  display: inline-block;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -6em;
  bottom: 150px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #36b55c;
  padding: 15px 0;
  transition: .5s ;
}
#loadQuote:hover {
  background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.25);
}
#loadQuote:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
// prints quote
function printQuote(){

    var finalQuote = buildQuote();
    document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = finalQuote;

    var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.background = color;
    document.loadQuote.style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Thank you

Comment: where is the HTML?

Comment: Add your html code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your element selector is incorrect. Use `document.getElementById` to select the element.

```
// prints quote
function printQuote(){

    var finalQuote = buildQuote();
    document.getElementById('quote-box').innerHTML = finalQuote;

    var color = '#'+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    document.body.style.background = color;
    //BELOW LINE IS THE CHANGED CODE
    document.getElementById('loadQuote').style.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an issue at this line:

`document.loadQuote.style.backgroundColor = color;`;

basically `loadQuote` is not an object in `document`.

Instead you need to select a DOM element using `document.getElementById()` like:

`document.getElementById('loadQuote'); // if you have a DOM element with ID loadQuote`

Or using `Document.querySelector()` passing a CSS selector, just an example:

`document.querySelector('.loadQuote'); // if you DOM element has .loadQuote appplied`

More information on `document.querySelector()` can be found here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector